# Hosting streaming content

Tags: drupal, streaming, hosting

I am administering a drupal based website for a small company. We want to start offering our customers video content, streaming preferably.

What we would like to do is have a log-in on the website where after authentication the user could access the videos.

Since I am quite new to do this I don't know 
A., what streaming provider to use, lot of people mentioning amazon s3
b., is it possible if using amazon s3 to have my conent be "secured" so only people with neccessary login details access it.

(There is no need for purchasing infrastructure. We hand out the login/password to the customer personally, we just want that if someone copy/pastes the link he or she would not be able to watch it)

I just need some general guidline, googling streaming hosting gives up way to much results and I couldn't find the best solution for this type of question... :(

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://wistia.com/ its one of the best service.

As for showing the video you embed them in a content type and set permission for that type for authenticated users.

This is a basic example. If you needs is more complicate then you can try making a module or use commerce module .

Cheers,
Vishal